# Root with slug rails 4 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-url, friendly-id

Currently I'm using `friendlyID` gem and I just want to redirect my application to a root with slug if the user is authenticaated.

**url**

```
http://localhost:3000/companyABC/dashboard
```

Here's my current code

```
  authenticated :employer do
    root to: redirect("/:slug/dashboard"), as: :employer_root
  end

  namespace :company, path: "/:slug" do
    resources :dashboard
    namespace :settings do
      resources :collaborators
    end
  end
```

but the problem is when I sign in it redirects me to 
`http://localhost:3000/:slug/dashboard`

Comment: I'm afraid you need to set `root` explicitly. What you can do, is in the action bound to root check if user is authenticated and render different views accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use lambdas in routes, so it's impossible to access DB and fetch company's slug in routes.

But if you use devise, you can overwrite method **#after_sign_in_path_for**, so user will be redirected not to root_url but to specified url instead. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    company_dashboards_url(user.company)
  end
end
```

More information here: [devise docs about **after_sign_in_path_for**](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for)

Comment: Nice thanks for giving me a hint. I thought I can request the slug in the routes.